# How create a base64 string from a canvas Windows Phone 8.1(Universal app)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have an application capturing a signature, I already drawing the signature now I want to capture the information and create a base64 string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry here is the code that worked for me, is not perfect. Feel free to review and if you find anything please provide feedback. Thanks

In this example the canvas name is Display

```
    private async Task<string> generateBase64Bitmap()
    {
        // Initialization  

        try
        {
            // Initialization.  
            Size canvasSize = this.Display.RenderSize;
            Point defaultPoint = this.Display.RenderTransformOrigin;
            // Sezing to output image dimension.  
            this.Display.Measure(canvasSize);
            this.Display.UpdateLayout();
            this.Display.Arrange(new Rect(defaultPoint, canvasSize));
            // Convert canvas to bmp.  
            var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await bmp.RenderAsync(this.Display, (int)(this.Display.ActualWidth / 4), (int)(this.Display.ActualHeight / 4));
            // Setting.  
            var bitmap = (RenderTargetBitmap) bmp;

            //var bytes = (await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync()).ToArray();
            return await toBase64(bitmap);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //this.ShowMessage(ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }


    private async Task<string> toBase64(RenderTargetBitmap bmp)
    {
        var img = (await bmp.GetPixelsAsync()).ToArray();

        var encoded = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(
            BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, encoded);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
            (uint)bmp.PixelWidth, (uint)bmp.PixelHeight, 96, 96, img);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        encoded.Seek(0);

        //read bytes
        var bytes = new byte[encoded.Size];
        await encoded.AsStream().ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
```

To call the method use(add async to your method):

```
string encodedImgBase64 = await generateBase64Bitmap();
```